# TextBox, не работает привязка в ToolTip

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Простейший код WPF, изучаю Binding:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="PathTextBox" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="D:\[Kawaiika-Raws] (2013) Shingeki no Kyojin S1 [BDRip 1920x1080 HEVC FLAC]\Bonus\Scans" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,5,10,0" Height="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="true" Background="{x:Null}">
            <TextBox.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=PathTextBox}" />
                </ToolTip>
            </TextBox.ToolTip>
        </TextBox>
```

В итоге при наведении мышки наTextBox я получаю такой результат, как на картинке.[image: Не работает ToolTip]

Почему не работает привязка? Эта строка  `{Binding Text, ElementName=PathTextBox}`в контексте привязки к другим элементам управления вроде текста другого TextBox или Label работает прекрасно, а в ToolTip не хочет. Что я пропускаю?

Comment: `ToolTip` не является UI свойством, ну а `ElementName` работает только с ними. В таких случаях используют обычно `x:Reference`, ну или ищут предка примерно так: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}" />`. Хороший ответ [про разницу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244917/6808809) между ними.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "ToolTip не является UI свойством" Так у меня в ToolTip объявлен TextBlock со свойством Text. Через **x:Reference** вообще исключение вылетает System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Comment: `Так у меня в ToolTip объявлен TextBlock` - и..? Запустите отладку, и откройте визуальное дерево элементов, увидите там ToolTip? Не думаю. Вы вашему `TextBox`'у задаете свойство `ToolTip`, которое не является UI свойством, ну и внутри этого не UI свойства вы используете поиск по UI дереву, вот и не находит. Что касается `x:Reference` и ошибки - там скорей всего ошибка зацикленности, чтоб это избежать, можете отделить текст, вынеся его в другой контрол. Ну или как я вам показал выше, поиском предка. ([EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53312264/6808809)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Забыл добавить, что через поиск предков выдается аналогичный результат. Насчет зацикленности, т.е. содержимое подсказки не может ссылаться на контрол, для которого создается эта подсказка, так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolTip` не является частью визуального дерева, поэтому привязка по `ElementName` или `RelativeSource` не сработает. Но если вам нужен просто текст, то можно проще.

```xml
<TextBox Text="..."
         ...
         ToolTip="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Ну либо через `PlacementTarget`

```xml
<TextBox Text="...">
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

Кстати, тот же самый фокус вас ждет с `ContextMenu` и `Popup`.

Comment: первый вариант прям то, что мне нужно в данном случае. Спасибо!